# How to print floats from LLVM IR?

Tags: printf, llvm, llvm-ir, c-standard-library

I have a problem using the `printf()` function from within LLVM IR. I just want to print the value of a float but I just get `0.000000`. It works fine for integers and strings but not floats.

Simple example:

```
@.fstr = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%f\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define i32 @main() {
    %1 = getelementptr [4 x i8],[4 x i8]* @.fstr, i64 0, i64 0
    %2 = call i32 @printf(i8* %1, double 2.0)
    %3 = call i32 @printf(i8* %1, float 2.0)
    ret i32 0
}
```

When I compile this with LLVM and link it with Clang and run the executable I get:

```
0.000000
0.000000
```

Same result if I run the .bc file  with `lli`. I have read this relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144506/printf-doesnt-work-for-floats-in-llvm-ir?newreg=9820b32813ec440e82bfa11d5fc5e684) but as you see it doesn't work with doubles either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On running your example using `lli-10` I get a
`@printf' defined with type 'i32 (i8*, ...)*' but expected 'i32 (i8*, double)*'` error rather than a successful call that prints 0.000000.

This error is expected, and the reason why is explained [here](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2013-December/068398.html). The relevant bit from the post is

> ... if the type in front of the call is a
> function pointer type, then that is used *as the type of the thing being
> called*, while if it's not, then it is used *as the return type*, and the
> type of the call is inferred from the arguments present on the instruction.

That is why LLVM infers `printf`'s type in the first call as `i32 (i8*, double)*` but later finds out it's declared as `i32 (i8*, ...)*`. To fix this simply annotate the calls properly,

```
%2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* %1, double 2.0)
%3 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* %1, float 2.0)
```

You'd quickly notice that the second `printf` call still prints 0.000000. See [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63156309/8925535)